# Make div stay contained within its parent mouse move

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div within another div and when the user hovers over the parent the inner div follows the mouse position. However, when the mouse is on the edge of the parent the child's border goes beyond the parents. I want to make it so the child div's border always stays contained within its parents.

I made a fiddle of what I've made so far: https://jsfiddle.net/0ahqoycg

A solution I'm thinking about is checking if the inner div's `top` attribute is a certain length from the outer's `top`, and if it is then stop the mouse position tracking, same goes for left, right, and bottom.

Can anyone tell me if there's a good way to keep the child's borders contained within its parents?

Comment: You might like this library: http://tether.io/

Comment: u inner not child outer, becouse use another stream by reason positiion: absolute. what information u want place to inner?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov what's that?

Comment: becouse that so work positiion absolute

Comment: if u want use pic with inner, u can use css cursor: url('');

Comment: Finally after 35 mins got it. @MarksCode have a look at my soln.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Using `.offset()` , `.width()` and `.height()` to calculate
  permissible co-ordinates.
- Caching all selectors in variables  and precomputing as much outside
  to boost performance because of the rather large number of
  `mouseover` events being generated.
- 2 sections marked as `//fine tune tweaks` are used to ease off the few last
  missed events before boundary crossed by over-riding position to
  boundary limit.

```js
var innerDiv = $('#inner');
var outerDiv = $('#outer');
var outDim = outerDiv.offset();
outDim.right = (outDim.left + outerDiv.width());
outDim.bottom = (outDim.top + outerDiv.height());
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var x = (e.clientX) - 15;
  var y = (e.clientY) - 15;
  var x_allowed = x >= outDim.left && x <= (outDim.right - innerDiv.width());
  var y_allowed = y >= outDim.top && y <= (outDim.bottom - innerDiv.height());
  if (y_allowed) {
    innerDiv.css({
      top: y + 'px',
    });
  } else {
    //fine tune tweaks
    if (y >= outDim.top) {
      innerDiv.css({
        top: (outDim.bottom - innerDiv.height()) + 'px',
      });
    }
    if (y <= (outDim.bottom - innerDiv.height())) {
      innerDiv.css({
        top: outDim.top + 'px',
      });
    }
  }

  if (x_allowed) {
    innerDiv.css({
      left: x + 'px'
    });
  } else {
    //fine tune tweaks
    if (x >= outDim.left) {
      innerDiv.css({
        left: outDim.right - innerDiv.width() + 'px',
      });
    }
    if (x <= (outDim.right - innerDiv.width())) {
      innerDiv.css({
        left: outDim.left + 'px',
      });
    }
  }


});
```

```css
#wrap {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#inner {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's really awesome, thanks so much. Do you know if there would be a way to allow the inner div to still move and be contained even if the mouse is near the edge of the outer div? It feels kind of weird when the inner div gets 'stuck' when the mouse is near the edge of the outer div.

Comment: @MarksCode greedy huh :D, it's glitchy when u move fast. Move slow it works.!! :D but yes, I'll try to optimise. But if it solved the issue, accept it. btw I'll keep updating the code. I've got kinda obsessed by it.

Comment: I accepted it, I'm happy your find this so interesting. There's a library someone mentioned in the comments called tether.io but doing this independently would be much cooler.

Comment: Also check out the answer below yours, it looks like it does the job pretty well.

Comment: that was what i was saying i was editing earlier. just made x and y independant and cached all variables outside the event. check now. much faster and smoother.

Comment: That's much better. I like how much smoother it is. There's a tiny bug when moving around the inner box sometimes can't go all the way to the edge, but overall this is really nice. No clue who downvoted :(

Comment: @MarksCode I'm fixing that, 1 min

Comment: @MarksCode fixed all, tellme if there are any more bugs you find!!

Comment: Wow this is amazing. Nice job!!! Runs and looks great. Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of...

```
  var innerDiv = $('#inner');
  var outerDiv = $('#outer');
  innerDivWidth = innerDiv.outerWidth();
  innerDivHeight = innerDiv.outerHeight();
  var offset = outerDiv.offset();
  var l = offset.left + 15;
  var t = offset.top + 15;
  var h = outerDiv.outerHeight();
  var w = outerDiv.outerWidth();

  var maxx = l + w - innerDivWidth;
  var maxy = t + h - innerDivHeight;


  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if(e.clientY <= maxy && e.clientY >= t) {
    $('#inner').css({
        top: (e.clientY - 15) + 'px'
    });
    } 
    if(e.clientX  <= maxx && e.clientX  >= l) {
    $('#inner').css({
        left: (e.clientX - 15) + 'px'
    });
    }
  });
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnz29to6/1/)

One thing to keep in mind is that, you should keep the code executed on the firing of an event, **very lean**. Specially since events like `mousemove` can get fired upto hundreds of times per second.

Excerpt from [Jquery Doc](https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/).

> Keep in mind that the mousemove event is triggered whenever the mouse
>   pointer moves, even for a pixel. This means that hundreds of events
>   can be generated over a very small amount of time. If the handler has
>   to do any significant processing, or if multiple handlers for the
>   event exist, this can be a serious performance drain on the browser.
>   It is important, therefore, to optimize mousemove handlers as much as
>   possible, and to unbind them as soon as they are no longer needed.

Comment: For your query *to allow the inner div to still move and be contained even if the mouse is near the edge of the outer div?* this solution works.